# How to make an outline square?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to start a build in a 10x10 chunk, but unfortunately I don't know how to form a square outline around the 10 by 10 chunks using smooth stone quickly. I've tried using the `/fill` commands and none of them seem to work.

"Outline" meaning there is a 1 thick outline of smooth stone around the 10x10 chunks.

So is there any other quick way to do this?

Comment: Might be worth looking into WorldEdit - the `//walls` command handles this perfectly.

Comment: Yup @Corsaka I found that out too after searching, I installed and it works great :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no one command for a 2D outline. You can either do it with the four obvious commands for each side or you can use one command to fill the entire square and then a second one to empty the inside, if the existing blocks inside don't matter, but that causes more lag (mostly light updates, better in 1.20+). If they do matter, you can do that elsewhere first and then use `/clone … filtered` to copy it over, but that costs even more performance. I would recommend the four command method.

Comment: Really? Darn, oh well I'll use your side by side tactic then i guess, better than nothing. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while, and thanks to @Corsaka, the WorldEdit mod has a `//walls` command to perform this where you set the 2 positions using a wooden axe and then use the command (make sure to type the block you want to make the walls with too).